# sqldf R code that renames variables based on a pattern

Tags: sql, r, list, sqldf

I have a list of over 50,000 rows in csv format of different names with the same underlying 5 digit code below:

```
Code             Name
25000            James John Junior
RA25000          James Junior
RA2500009        James J. Junior
RA27000          Bill Hope
RA2800009        Donna Scott
28000            Donna Love Scott
```

Since the list shares the same underlying code, for example 25000, how can I change the list to have the name associated with that underlying code (25000 for example) using the `sqldf` package in R (like below). Using only Rstudio.

```
Code             Name
25000            James John Junior
RA25000          James John Junior
RA2500009        James John Junior
RA27000          Bill Hope
RA2800009        Donna Love Scott
28000            Donna Love Scott
```

Note, I want to avoid having to individually type 25000, then 27000, then 28000 in the code because the list itself has over 50,000 rows and possibly 40,000 variations of the underlying code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your version of `sqldf` supports [common table expressions](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html) (SQLite 3.8.3+), consider cleaning *Code* with `SUBSTR` and `REPLACE` and join it to an aggregated CTE to align to name of maximum length. A final self join of CTE needed to map the clean name.

```sql
WITH agg AS
   (SELECT SUBSTR(REPLACE([Code], 'RA', ''),1,5) AS CleanCode, 
           MAX(LENGTH([Name])) AS MaxLenName
    FROM myData
    GROUP BY SUBSTR(REPLACE([Code], 'RA', ''),1,5)
   ),
   sub AS 
   (SELECT SUBSTR(REPLACE([Code], 'RA', ''),1,5) AS CleanCode, 
           LENGTH([Name]) AS LenName,
           [Code],
           [Name]
    FROM myData
   )

SELECT sub.Code,
       sub2.Name
FROM sub
INNER JOIN agg
   ON agg.CleanCode = sub.CleanCode
LEFT JOIN sub as sub2
   ON agg.CleanCode = sub2.CleanCode
   AND agg.MaxLenName = sub2.LenName;
```

<kbd>[Online Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hd5vp9CdF33j29ZiMzxRKH/0)</kbd> *(click run at top)*

```
| Code      | Name              |
| --------- | ----------------- |
| 25000     | James John Junior |
| RA25000   | James John Junior |
| RA2500009 | James John Junior |
| RA27000   | Bill Hope         |
| RA2800009 | Donna Love Scott  |
| 28000     | Donna Love Scott  |
```

Comment: Can this be done in the R environment (RStudio) using the sqldf package? Because I don’t think my version of sqldf supports common table expressions

Comment: Try to upgrade `RSQLite` (a dependency of `sqldf`): `install.packages("RSQLite")`.

Comment: Also, what is specific error you receive? Be sure to wrap query in double quotes (not single) and replace *mydata* with your data frame name.

Answer (score 0):

Using the input shown reproducibly in the Note at the end perform a left self join.
`ltrim` removes any `A` or `R` on the left side of the Code of the first instance of `DF` and then `substr` takes the next 5 characters.  Match that to the second instance of `DF`'s `Code`.  If there can be other letters prefacing the number include them in the `AR` string.  If any upper case letters can appear then use `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`.

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select a.Code, coalesce(b.Name, a.Name) Name 
  from DF a left join DF b
  on substr(ltrim(a.Code, 'AR'), 1, 5) = b.Code")
```

giving:

```
       Code              Name
1     25000 James John Junior
2   RA25000 James John Junior
3 RA2500009 James John Junior
4   RA27000         Bill Hope
5 RA2800009  Donna Love Scott
6     28000  Donna Love Scott
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "Code             Name
25000            James John Junior
RA25000          James Junior
RA2500009        James J. Junior
RA27000          Bill Hope
RA2800009        Donna Scott
28000            Donna Love Scott"
Lines2 <- readLines(textConnection(Lines))
DF <- read.csv(text = sub(" +", ",", Lines2), header = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```

Comment: I understand that a.Code is the code column and b.Code is the new column being created but what would a.Name and b.Name be referring to?

Comment: There are two instances of DF, a and b, and they are both the same, i.e. they both have a Code and Name column.